# how to submit a form then redirect as submitting

Tags: javascript, html

I have a regular Form in which the user inputs data, although, the Form page "submit.php", actually takes about 6 seconds to complete the form request. Is there any way in JavaScript to redirect the user after they submit the form?

I need something like this, although this does NOT work, because the page is in the process of loading from submitting the form, (the JavaScript does not process while the page is loading, though, I need it to process while the page is loading.)

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id='resizer' name=\"ucode\" placeholder='username'>
    <input type='password' id='resizer' name=\"pcode\" placeholder='password'>
    <input type=\"submit\" src=\"submit.png\" onClick="redirect()">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function redirect() {
    document.getElementById(\'divid\').innerHTML = \'<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\;URL=something.pl\?ucode=..&pcode=...\">';
}
</script>

<div id=\"divid\"></div>
```

I'm NOT looking for a way to make my submit form load faster, my problem is that need this to submit to the server then load to a different page without waiting for the servers response.

Please don't tell me that the best way is to make my form load fast, I know it's the best way, though I don't want that.

Comment: Something that I have done in the past is to use ajax to submit to the form and then dynamicly change the page.  When the results are back I throw them onto the page in some<div> placed someplace on the page then turn off the <div>'s that are not needed.

Comment: Why not submit the form asynchronously, then redirect all in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the data through ajax on different page and then after redirect to someother page through location.href="url"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect before data is sent to server, but you might use AJAX to sent data and as soon it happen, on callback, just redirect

in general to redirect use: use location.reload() of location.href = "..."